# Creating a searchable image gallery with datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

Datatable is great when using data to display in tables. I like it's searching behavior.  I want to make a image gallery with same searching behavior.

**Jquery**

```
if ($("#tbl_images_list").length) {
    // Get parameters from the current URL 
    var oTable = $('#tbl_images_list').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,    

        ajax: {
            url: 'upload_images/fetch',
        },
        columns: [{
            data: null,                               
            render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                return '<img src="' + row.image_url + '" onerror="this.src=' 
                    + 'uploads/default.png' + '" width="400" height="200">';
            },
            name: 'image_url'
        },],
    });
}
```

**View**

```
<div class="body table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover d-flex" id="tbl_images_list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Image</th>   
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody >                               
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function fetch() 
{
    $model = Image::select('image_url');
    return Datatables::eloquent($model)->make(true);
}
```

As for now it is rendering just one column and images in a row.
What I can do here I can do something to make the rows side by side, everything will be awesome then.  Let me give a visible example.  So for now, here  what is on screen.

```
| Image (column_name) |
|   Row 1 (image_1)   |
|   Row 2 (image_2)   |
.....son on............
```

What I want is make rows adjacent to each other, I know it's stupid idea. But this idea would work here if it's possible.

```
| Image (column_name) |
| Row 1 (image_1)  | | Row 2 (image_2) | and so on...
```

I need help. Please tell me if it's possible, or any alternative way to achieve the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of an answer to your datatables question, but here are a couple of image search plugins you might be interested in

https://vestride.github.io/Shuffle/

https://yiotis.net/filterizr/#/